# Symfony Doctrine using max in Selectable Interface

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I was using this Stackoverflow as an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786937/how-to-use-a-findby-method-with-comparative-criteria):

Which looks like this:

```
$criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
$criteria->where($criteria->expr()->gt('prize', 200));

$result = $entityRepository->matching($criteria);
```

I would like to to use the max instead like this:

```
$criteria->where($criteria->expr()->max('prize'));
```

but get:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "max" of class "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ExpressionBuilder".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? As you see, you cannot use `max` as an expression in the `where` clause. You may have to manually write out the sql using a sub-query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475589/sql-server-how-to-use-an-aggregate-function-like-max-in-a-where-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you’re actually looking for the `max()` method of the Expression builder attached to the query builder `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr::max()`.

What you actually are looking for is:

```
$entityManager->createQueryBuilder()->expr()->max($x);
```

`$entityManager` is obviously an instance of your entity manager, which you’ll get through DI or the container.

Answer (score 2):

I [looked at the API](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/1.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ExpressionBuilder.html), and it does not have a max expression Comparison.

Here is the Criteria API for reference as well:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/1.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Criteria.html

I know querybuilder has a max expression, but this API does not.