# Getting records for last 'X' number of days from TimeStamps in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, unix

Trying to utilize MySQL Date and Time functions. Currently I have a table that shows a mailman's routes for the past 5 days. These values are stored as a time stamp in my database. I want all of the Street Addresses this mailman has visited in the past 3 days.

So far, I can do this following query:

```
 "SELECT RouteEndTime
  FROM Mailman GROUP BY RouteEndTime
  HAVING DATEDIFF(MAX(RouteEndTime), RouteEndTime) <= 3;"
```

but I only get back all of the RouteEnd values for all 15 rows

I'm looking at this list of resources:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_mysql.asp

Under  MySQL Date Functions, but there is no function that does what I need it to do.

Is there a function that I can use to get all the street addresses he visited in the most recent 3 days (starting from the most recent date in my db) The answer I'm looking for is basically all the street address names from January 5th, 4th and 3rd.

```
MailManID  | Street Address |  RouteStartTime        |  RouteEndTime

54         |  'Apple St'    |  '2018-01-05 09:00:00' | '2018-01-05 09:05:00'
54         |  'Bat St'      |  '2018-01-05 09:30:00' | '2018-01-05 09:35:00'
54         |  'Cat St'      |  '2018-01-05 09:45:00' | '2018-01-05 09:50:00'

54         |  'Kite St'     |  '2018-01-04 09:00:00' | '2018-01-04 09:05:00'
54         |  'Lemon St'    |  '2018-01-04 09:30:00' | '2018-01-04 09:35:00'
54         |  'Muppet St'   |  '2018-01-04 09:45:00' | '2018-01-04 09:50:00'

54         |  'Luke St'     |  '2018-01-03 09:00:00' | '2018-01-03 09:05:00'
54         |  'Ben St'      |  '2018-01-03 09:30:00' | '2018-01-03 09:35:00'
54         |  'Cow St'      |  '2018-01-03 09:45:00' | '2018-01-03 09:50:00'

54         |  'Hello St'    |  '2018-01-02 09:00:00' | '2018-01-02 09:05:00'
54         |  'Igloo St'    |  '2018-01-02 09:30:00' | '2018-01-02 09:35:00'
54         |  'Jump St'     |  '2018-01-02 09:45:00' | '2018-01-02 09:50:00'

54         |  'Yellow St'   |  '2018-01-01 09:00:00' | '2018-01-01 09:05:00'
54         |  'Blue St'     |  '2018-01-01 09:30:00' | '2018-01-01 09:35:00'
54         |  'Red St'      |  '2018-01-01 09:45:00' | '2018-01-01 09:50:00'
```

I want to return something like:

```
'Apple St' '2018-01-05 09:00:00' '2018-01-05 09:05:00'
'Bat St' '2018-01-05 09:30:00' '2018-01-05 09:35:00'
'Cat St''2018-01-05 09:45:00' '2018-01-05 09:50:00'
'Kite St''2018-01-04 09:00:00' '2018-01-04 09:05:00'
'Lemon St''2018-01-04 09:30:00' '2018-01-04 09:35:00'
'Muppet St''2018-01-04 09:45:00' '2018-01-04 09:50:00'
'Luke St''2018-01-03 09:00:00' '2018-01-03 09:05:00'
'Ben St''2018-01-03 09:30:00' '2018-01-03 09:35:00'
'Cow St''2018-01-03 09:45:00' '2018-01-03 09:50:00'
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Incidentally, a unix timestamp is simply the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970. What you've provided above is just a timestamp

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Strawberry. Regarding the link you posted, is the table I've provided not good enough or missing some important information?

Comment: Both , I'd say. But the accepted answer at the link provided is very thorough.

Answer (score 3):

A better source of information about MySQL is [straight from their own documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) In that list you will see `DATEDIFF()` which gives the difference in days between two dates.

```
... WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), RouteStartTime) <= 3
```

or something like that will get you what you need.

If you want exactly three days to the second, it's easier just to use the timestamps:

```
... WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60*60*24*3) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(RouteStartTime)
```

(60*60*24*3 is the number of seconds in three days)

To measure your three days from the last timestamp in your database, you need to use the MAX() function. Cribbing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475589/sql-server-how-to-use-an-aggregate-function-like-max-in-a-where-clause), we see that `WHERE` won't allow `MAX()` (except as a subquery, but `HAVING` will:

```
... HAVING DATEDIFF(MAX(RouteStartTime), RoutStartTime) <= 3
```

`HAVING` is supposed to be for aggregate functions, but works for `MAX()` without a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry - I understand the DATEDIFF function better now however, what if I wanted the the last 3 days from the last day in the data set? So it would be the last 3 days starting from the most recent date?

Comment: That is trickier. Rather than NOW(), you need to use the aggregate function MAX() on the column, with requires a subquery. Fortunately an easy one. I'll update the answer.

Comment: So, @Jerry in omitting the GROUP BY in the above statement, doesn't it just default to behaving like the WHERE clause?

Comment: It does (pretty much), but still allows `MAX()`, where `WHERE` does not. Note that in that answer I linked to, other answers recommend a join on the same table instead.